# is it possible to build a debugger around the java scripting engine?

Tags: java, javascript, documentation, debugging, code-documentation

we are using the java 6 scripting engine in our product, and now we are thinking on adding some debugging abilities.

my question is:

1. is it possible? does the java 6 scripting engine has the same capabilities like rhino as far as debugging.
2. some documentation about how to start doing it, some code samples any information would be great since i could not find anything on the web.

thanks

Comment: I believe it is possible - I don't have any links, but I'd start with searching for JPDA and Rhino.

Comment: another thing that i would like to achieve is to be able to stop the process of the script evaluation after X amount of seconds. like the question above if you have any information about how to do it... ill be grateful..

Comment: Are you trying to build a Java debugger or a JavaScript debugger?

Comment: we are using java and 
i would like to use the java scripting engine to create a debugger for the script it evaluates

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by looking at how the open source Firebug (www.getfirebug.com) tool is implemented, unless you're completely wedded to the idea of a "pure" sand-boxed Rhino environment (and even then Firebug could probably teach you a few things).